Pyrogram userbot started ignoring messages from certain channels for no reason
For a long period of time I had a pyrogram userbot working well, but week ago it started ignoring/ not seeing messages in certain channels.
I've been playing around with filters but it didn't help.
I've used get_chat({{chat_id}}), and all information about channel was coming in and nothing was special about it.
Eventually i've removed all filters and started logging all messages so current code looks like this:
channels = [target["target"] for target in targets]

@app.on_disconnect()
def on_disconnect(client):
  log(client,"Disconnected")

@app.on_message(filters.all())
def handle_message(client, message):
  print(message)
  log(client,f"Received message: {message.text} \nfrom: {message.chat.title}")
  processing = False
  for target in targets:
    if message.chat.id == target.get("target") and target.get("chat_duplication",False):
      log(client,f"Duplicating message: {message.text} \nfrom: {message.chat.title} \nto: {app.get_chat(target.get('send_to')).title}")
      processing = True
      duplicate(app, client, message)
  if not processing:
    log(client,f"Skipping message from: {message.chat.title}")

def run_telegram_bot():
  app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run_telegram_bot()

but messages from those channels aren't getting logged in the received log.

it broke on may 28 2024, to me, without any cose change. Weird thing is some channels/chats forwards keep working
